# How do i create rules in MYSQL, for a subscription model?

Tags: php, mysql, database, rules

I am creating a website, but how do i create rules for users that have a free subscription, and rules for a premium subscription. i want free userd to only be limited to 10GB and see adverts, but the premium users dont have ads and can upload up to 100gb

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a framework for your website (e.g. Symfony 3) you can handle this with php.
The login script decides if the user is free or subscribed user and therefore will allow or deny adverts or upload limits.

Back to the symfony example, I would handle this with the FOSUserBundle setting the restrictions for each user by defaults.
The adverts could check the parameters for the non-paying free subscription users and display adverts or don't even load them if the user is identified as premium user.

Hope this answer gives you a general idea to this general question.